# CSS div with auto height always on bottom

Tags: html, css

```css
.comments_modal {
  height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 250px;
}
.footer {
    min-height:100px;
    border:1px solid blue;

    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.main_div {
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%; width:300px; position: absolute;">
    
    <div class="main_div">
    
    <div class="comments_modal">
float height block
</div>
        
    <div  class="footer">
        
        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg        dfgdfgdfg
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
</div>
```

I have floating height footer (100px - 300px). I can't to place div with auto height always on bottom. Also, main div should be of  "position:absolute"
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXllt.png)

Comment: Are you using `position: fixed`?

Comment: yes, but then footer overlayed of div above (content)

Comment: can you paste your code

Comment: Please post an example of your markup and CSS.